# Switching between Tables

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a ViewModel that supports 3 lists but the user only needs to see one at a time.

In iOS we use a Segmented Control to switch the Visibility. What control should I be using in Android. Is it tabs? Tabs seem to be a way of switching from one View to another whereas I just want to set some ShowTableX or ShowTableY properties on a ViewModel.

FWIW this is a sample of the kind of UI I am talking about

[image: screenshot of Android app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle this. You could have a ViewPager and a TabLayout (from the Support Design package) and switch between pages in the ViewPager.

If you don't want to use a ViewPager and simply toggle visibility on your layouts, you can use the TabLayout without a ViewPager and add Tabs yourself and listen to the TabSelected event it gives you and toggle visibility based on which Tab is selected.

Comment: "Support Design package"? Is that a Material thing?

Comment: That is material, yes.